# How to change permissions for a file in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, permissions, unix

I run the file ./schema.pg.sh with the command `sudo ./schema.pg.sh` in /sql directory. But the terminal throws an error:

```bash
could not change directory to "/sql": Permission denied
```

Script I am running:

```
echo -n "you are running $0 type yes to continue: "
read -r answer
[ "$answer" != "yes" ] && exit

cat schema.pg.sql | sudo -u postgres psql
```

I found out that this command is causing the error:

```bash
sudo -u postgres psql
```

But my knowledge is not enough to find the cause and fix the error.

Сommand `ls -l sql/` shows permissions like this:

```bash
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alex alex 127823 июн 25 17:58 data.sql
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alex alex    426 июн 25 17:58 drop.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex     67 июн 25 17:58 dump.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex    204 июн 25 17:58 reload.demo.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex    155 июн 25 17:58 reload.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex    475 июн 25 17:58 reset.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex    168 июн 25 17:58 schema.demo.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex    140 июн 25 17:58 schema.pg.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex    192 июн 25 17:58 schema.pg.sql
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alex alex    641 июн 25 17:58 triggers.sql
```

Command `ls -ld /sql` gives output like this:

```bash
drwxrwxrwx 2 alex alex 4096 июн 25 17:58 sql/
```

I used `sudo chmod +x /sql` and `sudo chmod +x schema.pg.sh` but the permissions didn't change. And when you enter the command `mount | grep $(df -P /sql | awk 'NR==2{print $1}') | awk '$0=$5'` output:

```bash
ext4
```

Comment: Based on what you have provided the correct permissions should be 755 (I.e read and execute permissions for everyone role). You cannot change the permissions without first changing to root due to the lack of read permissions

Comment: What is the result of `ls -ld /sql` to see permission of `/sql` directory (relative to your first error) ?

Comment: @ArnaudValmary ```drwxrwxrwx 2 alex alex 4096 июн 25 17:58 sql/``` I added this output to the question.

Comment: Do you perform a `cd /sql` in your script ? With another user (do you change user in your script) ?
What is the first line of your script (the shebang) ?

Comment: @ArnaudValmary This is the whole script:

'echo -n "you are running $0 type yes to continue: "
 read -r answer
 [ "$answer" != "yes" ] && exit
 cat schema.pg.sql | sudo -u postgres psql'